# Inline Initialization of Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables, initialization

I have to set the value of exp_valu if the value of val1 is 1. I tried to this using the below code, but somehow it is failing. Where am I making mistake?

```
val1=1
val2=0

exp_valu = if val1: 1 else: 2
print(exp_valu)
```

Comment: `exp_valu = 1 if val1 == 1 else 2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 
`exp_valu= 1 if val1 == 1 else 2` 
In line if statmet not excpecting to have`:` in it.
The one line if statment look like

```
value if condition else vale
```